# PHPExcel duplicate style only duplicate the first cell even when range of cell is given

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to copy styles from a range of cells in a template file and paste it to another range of cells in another file and then save the resulting file.  I experimented on a small subset of my Excel file before I fully implemented it, but I found a strange result.

Here is my code snippet...

```
include "../class/PHPExcel.php";
include "../class/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
include "../class/PHPExcel/Cell.php";

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$frTemplate = $reader->load("document/Template/FR-001 Template.xlsx");
$frTemplate->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$frTemplate->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow(3, 6, $year);

//copy style
$cellStyle = $frTemplate->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E47:E49');
$frTemplate->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($cellStyle, 'E52:E54');

//copy value
$cellValues = $frTemplate->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('E47:E49');
$frTemplate->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValues, null,'E52');

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($frTemplate, "Excel2007");
$writer->save("document/Template/FR-001 2017.xlsx");

echo "Done";
```

Here is an image of the copied Excel file...

[Copied File-Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6Q4.jpg)

And here is an image of the target file...

[Result-Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdpcQ.jpg)

I'm trying to apply the code with another data, and I found that -

- "Merge cell" style cannot be copied
- When a range of cells is copied, the only style copied is the first cell (upper left)

Sadly, I cannot post the evidence of the above case as my reputation is still very low (It is my first question in Stack Overflow!)

So, can you please tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you wish to include an image in the body of a Question, rather than as a link to a file, then replace `[image description][1]` with `![][1]`.  Replace `1` with whatever number is being used for that image.  Also, the image description is not displayed anywhere in this case but is still required, hence the empty set of brackets.

Comment: @toonice Aaarrggh, I cannot post the image in the body of the question, my reputation is still too low. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct:

`"Merge cell"` is not an aspect of style; it's part of the `structure` of the worksheet, so it cannot be "copied" by duplicateStyle. If you want to merge cells, you need to use the `mergeCells()` method for each merge range that you want to set.

The `duplicateStyle()` method copies a style to a range of cells; it doesn't copy multiple styles to a new range. The `getStyle()` method allows a range for the purpose of setting a style against all cells in that range, but only returns the style of the first cell within that range. You need to duplicate each different style to its own range.

Comment: Woow, thanks for the clarification! I thought for sure that there is something wrong with my code.